# idea cannot hot deploy files under src/main/resources

Tags: intellij-idea

i am using idea ultimate 2020.3

i created a maven web project.

when i changed `java` or `jsp` files and choose `update class and resources`, they can be hot deploy.

however, if i changed files under `src/main/resources`, e.g. mybatis xml file under src/main/resouces/config/mapper, they cannot be hot deploy.

how can i fix it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are deploying an **exploded** artifact, see [Update applications on application servers﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html)

Also make sure the module has configured [Web resources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-web-application-support.html) (has the **Web** facet with **Web Resource Directories** and **Source Roots** [configured](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-web-application-support.html#Enabling_Web_Application_Support-6-chapter):

[image]

Comment: yes, it is war exploded. And the module has configured web resources as your screenshot shown. Plz check my last screenshot which i added just now. Thanks!